# Difference is Bluetooth Smart and Bluetooth audio

Tags: audio, bluetooth, signal-processing, bluetooth-low-energy, smart

My name is Raveen Baloo. I have been doing a lot of research on the types of Bluetooth module. For my project, i do need a bluetooth which will be able to have simple communication with a mobile app, sending over sensor data and do simple command. The bluetooth chip should also be able to send continues data (playing music). Now, while doing my research, i found that bluetooth smart will be able to send data periodically and audio bluetooth sends continues data with DPS.

So will a Bluetooth Smart or smart ready be able to send continues data (streaming music) and will it be as good as the Bluetooth audio module which has DPS and aptx.?

Thanking in advance for you help guys. 
Feel free to ask me if you dont understand my question. I'll try my level best to explain it again. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth Low Energy does not stream data like classic Bluetooth.

BLE works by setting up short-lived connections to transmit a small amount of data quickly.  You can, conceivably, construct a system where you do this fast enough that you can push enough data through the link to stream audio at some level of quality, but it's not designed for that.

BLE has huge advantages in allowing long battery life and allowing a large number of sensors to use the same central device.  So if you don't require either of those advantages, and you need to stream data, then I would recommend you use classic Bluetooth.

You mentioned the "smart ready" chips in your post - those can do both BLE and classic Bluetooth.  I don't know if they can do them at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. :)
I should probably test it out to see the quality of music from both classic and BLE, and make a decision from there.

Comment: @RaveenBaloo:  You are most welcome.  If you found my answer helpful, please upvote it (click the "up" arrow next my answer).  Additionally, if you my answer fully answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer.  best of luck, and welcome to Stack Exchange EE.